# How to count number of character after .(dot) in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have number format table with data like.

```
ID    NUMFMT

1     #############.####
2     #############.###
3     #############.##
```

i need to write function that retrieve number of character after . in db2.

Comment: [locate_in_string](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0054098.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply the length - the position of the dot:

```
select len(numfmt) - locate_in_string(numfmt, '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

its <> efficient but it gives what you need !!

```
select len(' #############.###')- len(substring(' #############.###',0,PATINDEX('%.%',' #############.###')))-1
```

Comment: you can put it as function !!